# Replace Chrome OS and install Ubuntu on an Lenovo C330 ARM processor laptop

Tags: usb, flash, usb-drive, chromebook, chroot

I have tried everything. Developer mode and `cd;bash <(curl https://johnlewis.ie/flash_cb_fw.sh)` which just restarts my laptop and beeps. I've tried booting from USB but it just beeps when I try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. If anyone has any other ideas please help.